# There isn't a GitHub Pages site here. Error 404 con proyecto VUE

Tags: vue.js, git, github

He creado un repositorio de mi app de vue en github en gh-pages, con la intención de poder visualizarla mediante una url. https://eima6.github.io/Mi-Pagina-Web/ . Pero el enlace me da el siguiente error "There isn't a GitHub Pages site here." Los archivos de deploy.sh y vue.config.js están correctos, al igual que el username. Llevo un rato tratando de solucionar el problema y no doy con la solución.¿Alguna sugerencia? Aquí en enlace al repositorio.. https://github.com/Eima6/Mi-Pagina-Web

Comment: Me parece que debes compilar tu proyecto para visualizarlo

Comment: Ya lo compile con esta línea en la consola ./deploy.sh